# Resources for undergraduate knot theory

Tags: undergraduate-education, resource-request, topology

I am going to teach a 400-level topics class on knot theory at an American, mid-sized, public university. Prerequisites include multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and a proof course, but no exposure to topology or abstract algebra.

Do you know of resources for such a course? Notes, exercises, etc?

What I have so far:

- Books: Livingston, Adams, Crowell/Fox, Prasolov
- Visualization aid: http://www.knotplot.com/

Comment: Check out Topology Now!, Messer and Straffin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know much about knot theory but I know that Meike Akveld taught knot theory at both high school and university level. Here's a bibliography of one of her courses at ETH Zürich:

https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/knot/bibliography_FS2015.pdf

It includes Englisch and German books both for high school and university level. I only list English books for university level:

> General books about knots - accessible to (under-)graduate students:
>
> - M.A. Armstrong, *Basic Topology*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag, 1983 - Chapter 10 is devoted to knots.
> - G. Burde, H. Zieschang, *Knots*, Walter de Gruyter & Co., Berlin, 1985.
> - A.Kawauchi, *A Survey of Knot Theory*, Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 1996.
> - W.B.R. Lickorish, An Introduction to Knot Theory, Springer-Verlag. New York, 1997.
> - C. Livingston, *Knotentheorie für Einsteiger*, Vieweg, 1995 (also available in English).
> - K. Murasugi, *Knot Theory & Its Applications*, Chapters 5 and 6, Birkhäuser Boston, 2008.
> - J. Roberts, *Knots Knotes*, unpublished lecture notes, 2010, http://math.ucsd.edu/~justin/Roberts-Knotes-Jan2015.pdf.
> - D. Rolfsen, *Knots and Links*, AMS Chelsea Publishing, 2003.

There are still old exercises and solutions from the class available online [here](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/knot/uebungen.html). They usually get deleted a year or two after the class, so I'd download them just in case. Plus, you can find some hand-drawn examples on the [lecture website](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2015/math/knot.html) itself.

Answer (score 7):

You may find the [SageMath knot and links capabilities](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/knots/sage/knots/knot.html) useful for computation and visualization.

The [Knot Atlas](http://katlas.org/wiki/Main_Page) might be a bit more comprehensive than you are looking for but is certainly a reference to be quite aware of.